# Dropdown menu continues to stay after browser expanded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a responsive menu and I have some problems with it 
if you run this code in your laptop in full screen format then change browser width below the breakpoint at 943px, menu changes to mobile format and in this case if you select for example "about option " it's dropdown appears. Howevere if you resize the screen back to full size without first closing "about" drop down, it did not disappear in full screen, it continues to stay even after the browser is fully expanded. and it looks messed up
any idea? thanks

```js
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


    $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
    //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

    $(".menu > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\"></a>");



    $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".menu > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
 



    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 

});
```

```css
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    color: #333;
}

.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
megamenu.js STYLE STARTS HERE
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */


/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Screen style's
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.menu-container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}

.menu-mobile {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
}

.menu-mobile:after {
    content: "\f394";
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-25%);
    transform: translateY(-25%);
}

.menu-dropdown-icon:before {
    content: "\f489";
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.menu > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu > ul:before,
.menu > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.menu > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu > ul > li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.5em 3em;
    display: block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu > ul > li > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    background: none;
    float: left;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li a {
    color: #777;
    padding: .2em 0;
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .8em;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
    border: 0;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
    width: 300px;
    left: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a {
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
}


/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Mobile style's
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    .menu-container {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-dropdown-icon:before {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu > ul {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu > ul > li a {
        padding: 1.5em;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu > ul > li > ul {
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu > ul > li > ul > li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .menu > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .menu .show-on-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>megamenu.js | Last responsive megamenu you'll ever need</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="Mario Loncarek">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.Modernizr || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="menu-container">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://marioloncarek.com">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://marioloncarek.com">School</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="http://marioloncarek.com">Lidership</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Study</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Research</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Undergraduate research</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Masters research</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Funding</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marioloncarek.com">News</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://marioloncarek.com">Today</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://marioloncarek.com">Contact</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">School</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Lidership</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Study</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Study</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Empty sub</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
        <h3>megamenu.js - Last responsive megamenu you'll ever need</h3>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="js/megamenu.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please update the code in your question, and post only the relevant parts needed to reproduce the problem you have. Also, a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) could be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by the dropdown menu "continues to stay"?

Comment: hi thank you for your answering. in my menu i have 4 option and when  the browser width is shrunk below the breakpoint at 943px it changes to mobile format. in this case when i click on an option for example option 2 it's dropdown appears but after i resize the screen back to full size without first closing the option 2 drop down, it did now disappear in full screen and still shows the dropdown.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder hi man could u please take a look at this question i really need it and it really confused me thank u

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your problem is correctly, one way of doing what you want is by refreshing the webpage on resize.

Here is some JavaScript to do it:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    var resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    }, 300);
});
```

***UPDATE***:
Since it's just a menu, it would not be ideal to refresh the whole page so another way is to reduce its `z-index`, read more about the z-index: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

*Example:*

Javascript:

```
    var currentWidth ;

setInterval(function(){
    currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if(currentWidth < 983) { //983 or whatever threshold you want
        document.getElementsByClassName(".menu-container").style.zIndex = -999; //set the value to -999 just to be sure :)
    }
    else{
        document.getElementsByClassName(".menu-container").style.zIndex = 999;
    }
}, 300);
```

Comment: refreshing the page just to close a menu is a bad

Comment: thank you your first answer is worked but it has loading whole page problem.

Comment: give me a second and i will try to fix it :)

Comment: Try it now and change `#mDropDownMenu` to `.menu-container`

Comment: can you upload you files to dropbox or something so I ca get a better view on them?

Comment: thank you very much. i download the menu from this link
https://github.com/marioloncarek/megamenu-js

Comment: i will look into it :)

Comment: No problem :). But I checked the code (I implemented it into on of my own websites and it worked just fine). My suggestion is to check which part of the code you have changed when the bug first appear and start from there

Comment: it is not possible if you run index.html in your laptop in full screen format then change browser width below the breakpoint at 943px, menu changes to mobile format and in this case if you select for example "about option " it's dropdown appears then if you resize the screen back to full size without first closing "about" drop down, it did now disappear in full screen and still shows the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can "open" multiple sub-menus in mobile mode via this code:

```
$(".menu > ul > li").click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
        $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
    }
});
```

What you could do is add code that listens on the windows resize event and then fades the open menus. I did this with the following code. It remembers which sub-menu was opened and then on resize closes them:

```
    var openSubMenu = undefined;  // You want to store the open sub-menu here

    $('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI

    $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
    //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

    $(".menu > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

    //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
    //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
    //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
    //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover
    $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)
    $(".menu > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
            var thisItem = $(this).children("ul");
            if (openSubMenu && openSubMenu.get(0) != thisItem.get(0)) openSubMenu.fadeOut(0);
            openSubMenu = thisItem;
            openSubMenu.fadeToggle(150);
            //$(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });

    //When clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)
    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // When the window resizes clear any open windows
    $(window).resize(() => {
        if (openSubMenu && openSubMenu.css('display') === 'block') {
            openSubMenu.fadeOut(0);
            openSubMenu = undefined;
        }
    })
};
```